# numpy 2d array recursion

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, recursion

I have a numpy 2d array and i want to run a function that checks if values fron neighboring pixels are lowe than the given value (start value). If it’s  i'm trying to run recursive function with this pixel and value from the first one
It works fine for small arrays, but with a big one i have memory errors.
I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this.
In result I'm trying to get numpy 2d array with values that met this criteria.

code:

```
def check_neighbours(point_position, arr, water_level):

    locs = [[-1, -1], [-1, 0], [-1, 1], [0, -1],
            [0, 1], [1, 1], [1, -1], [1, 0]]

    if point in self.checked_cells:
        return True

    self.checked_cells.append(point)

    neighbours = [self.get_locs(x, point) for x in locs]

    for i in neighbours:
        n_point = arr[i[0], i[1]]
        if n_point <= water_level:
            check_neighbours(i, arr, water_level)



check_neigbours([10,20], 2darray, 70)
```

Comment: Please post the error message (the full traceback)

Comment: What is `self`?  `self.get_locs`?

Comment: Consider using a `dtype=bool` array for `checked_cells` (preallocated using `numpy.zeros`, with dimensions at least as large as `2darray`).

Comment: You're never changing `arr`, nor `water_level` but you're keep passing them as arguments. Removing those from the signature and using them as an instance variable would save you some memory. Also not sure if I understand clearly, what you're trying to solve, but you might be able to solve this without recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the insights. Turned out the i was looking for something like a [flood fill algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill).
To avoid the stack overflow i had to use an queue within a while loop.